# Centos 6 RAID10

Tags: linux, raid, centos6

Имеется машина с 4 sas по 140ГБ. Требуется на голом железе без ОС установить CentOS 6 с раид 10 на борту. Тоесть 2 раид 1 по 2 диска, и затем в раид 0 эти два, ну или как еще? Вобщем в итоге должен выйти раид из 2х дисков по 280гб. Раид ПРОГРАМНЫЙ

Comment: Ну а что ты уже делал и что у тебя не выходит?

Comment: Создал 2 raid1, а вот как их объеденить в раид 0 не знаю

Comment: А сразу сделать `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd` пробовал?